# Does FloraFibre help with colds?

Tags: cold

I've got a pretty bad cold and one of my friends gave me some Herbalife FloraFibre and told me that it would help. Is it likely to make a difference?

Comment: Hello @Casebash, could you explain how your question is related to exercise, because medical questions are off-topic

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Isn't this website about nutrition as well as exercise? That's what I thought from the name

Comment: Yes, but the FAQ states: Topics include exercise and training, nutrition and diets, and activities **related** to strength, endurance, agility, and cardiovascular fitness. Your question seems related to medical issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Considering your digestive tract makes up a huge portion of your immune system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_gastrointestinal_tract#Immune_function), it might since active cultures help promote better intestinal health. The problem with this supplement is that it provides a tiny amount of active cultures.

From Amazon:

> Each tablet provides millions of lactobacillus acidophilus cells.

Home made kefir or yogurt products can contain [trillions of cfu (colony forming units) per cup.](http://pecanbread.com/healingcrow/ferfun/conspiracy/conspiracy.html) Here's an [actual paper on the topic.](http://kefir.ilbello.com/articoli/k5.pdf)

So bottom line: even if active cultures do help improve immune system function then those tablets are pretty much 'homeopathic' in their dosing -a million to 1 compared to fresh kefir. So save your money and eat some fresh fermented diary products instead.